# Registering services through Java code (instead of web.xml)

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, service, web

I was wondering if there is any possibility to register a custom (RPC, JSON) service in Java code instead of writing it down to web.xml?

I'm planning on developing some core components that would give access to multiple connected services that can be added by someone else who can follow some simple steps (like specifying activator and so on).

Is that possible?

Best regards.

Comment: What's wrong with web.xml? It seems like using it would keep your code less tightly coupled. It's surely possible though to do what you're asking, but with the information you've provided I cannot answer with any specific examples. Basically, just instantiate the class in Java instead of web.xml.

Comment: How would you instantiate services? It's not like they are not going to be in web.xml. It's just that I want to have applications connected to central platform and providing their own services, views etc. The applications would have their own web.xmls, but I want those app's to NOT be inside webapps folder so they can only be accessible through the platform and not in any other way.

Comment: How would you instantiate services?  It depends on the code, the class, whether or not it's static, public, protected, private. For this, we'd need to see some form of code in order to give you an exact answer. If it's a service you wrote, I'd think `MyService service = new MyService();` could work.

Answer (score 0):

you could use Google's Guice on the server side to write the configuration in code.
Basically you add a GuiceListener to your web.xml, that highjacks and wires the configuration.

Take a look [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule) - they have code snippets to get you started:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule

Comment: I tried a simple JSON service and somewhy it doesn't work. I've added a simple ServletModule and registered a JSON service under some specific link, but I am not able to access it. Code is here: http://pastebin.com/VGXkmNN9 and http://pastebin.com/WC4vD9Rx

Comment: Forgot to mention I also added a listener to web.xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>project.server.ServletConfigurator</listener-class>
  </listener>
and configurateServlets() is called, but there's no effect while going to localhost:8080/serve or anything (also used the regular serve(...) method and the effect was the same) - the opposite to what you get when binding the service with web.xml.

Comment: OK, I missed the point about filtering/redirecting traffic to Guice. Now it works fine (with the redirecting in web.xml and putting @Singleton above the servlet class). Thanks. :)